# Image not saved in correct path

Tags: android, camera, storage, android-sdcard

I'm trying to save an image on local storage but the file is not saved in the designated location.
createImageFile provides the path and file name: (on SD card) 
`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_package_name/files/Pictures.`

**but** the image is actually saved on the device like a regular camera photo under the default DCIM folder, with a default file name:

`Internal shared storage\DCIM\100MEDIA`

File creation:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
imageFilePath1 = image.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: can you show up the path , on which u r storing image?

Comment: Use this path : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "App Name" +File.separoator + file name

Comment: Doesn't work. creating the path is okay. @hassanmirza

Comment: How do you save the image? I guess you pass **imageFilePath1** to some method, don't you?